# Me aparece este error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32con' pero tengo el paquete instalado

Tags: python, packages

**Ejecuto esta acción:**

```
python demo/demo.py --config-file projects/ISTR/confi
gs/ISTR-R50-3x.yaml --input ./ISTR/videoframe0000024.jpg --output ./ISTR/output --confidence-threshold 0.4 --opts MODEL.WEIGHTS ./ISTR/output/model_final.pth
```

**Me aparece este error:**

```
File "demo/demo.py", line 10, in <module>
   from detectron2.config import get_cfg
File "c:\users\lenovo\pycharmprojects\istr\istr_3\istr\detectron2\config\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
   from .compat import downgrade_config, upgrade_config
 File "c:\users\lenovo\pycharmprojects\istr\istr_3\istr\detectron2\config\compat.py", line 27, in <module>
   from .config import CfgNode as CN
 File "c:\users\lenovo\pycharmprojects\istr\istr_3\istr\detectron2\config\config.py", line 7, in <module>
   from fvcore.common.config import CfgNode as _CfgNode
 File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
 File "C:\Users\Lenovo\PycharmProjects\ISTR\venv\lib\site-packages\fvcore-0.1.5.post20211023-py3.8.egg\fvcore\common\config.py", line 8, in <module>
 File "C:\Users\Lenovo\PycharmProjects\ISTR\venv\lib\site-packages\iopath-0.1.7-py3.8.egg\iopath\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
   from iopath.common import (
 File "C:\Users\Lenovo\PycharmProjects\ISTR\venv\lib\site-packages\iopath-0.1.7-py3.8.egg\iopath\common\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
   from iopath.common.file_io import (
 File "C:\Users\Lenovo\PycharmProjects\ISTR\venv\lib\site-packages\iopath-0.1.7-py3.8.egg\iopath\common\file_io.py", line 8, in <module>
   import portalocker  # type: ignore
 File "C:\Users\Lenovo\PycharmProjects\ISTR\venv\lib\site-packages\portalocker-2.3.2-py3.8.egg\portalocker\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
   from . import portalocker
 File "C:\Users\Lenovo\PycharmProjects\ISTR\venv\lib\site-packages\portalocker-2.3.2-py3.8.egg\portalocker\portalocker.py", line 10, in <module>
   import win32con
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32con'
```

**Tengo el paquete win32 instalado y no se como solucionarlo**
El link al código de Github es el siguiente: https://github.com/hujiecpp/ISTR
Tengo el código clonado y hay bugs que están solucionados pero siempre me sale este fallo al intentar ejecutar

Comment: Adjunta un [repro] del código (énfasis en _mínimo_) _en_ la pregunta. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Los links se pueden caer. Si eliminas tu repositorio en Github por ejemplo. Si el link se cae tu pregunta queda inutil para aquellos que quieran recurrir a las respuestas a tu pregunta en el futuro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si, claro! Aquí lo describo mejor:

`pip install --upgrade pywin32==303 --force-reinstall`

Después he ejecutado el siguiente comando:

`cd C:/Users/.../anaconda3/envs/.../Scripts`

`python pywin32_postinstall.py -install`

Comment: Muchas gracias por todo! Soy nueva y voy un poco perdida...

Answer (score 0):

En primer lugar:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

Luego ejecuta el siguiente comando:

```
  pip install pypiwin32
```

Si eso no funciona, intenta lo siguiente:

```
python -m pip install pypiwin32
```

Si el comando de arriba da error intenta con

```
python -m pip install pywin32
```

Si no empleas entornos virtuales, y todo lo anterior no resuelve el problema, intenta las mismas operaciones pero en un terminal abierto como administrador.

Comment: He ejecutado: pip install pypiwin32 pero sigue apareciendo el mismo error.

Comment: Respuesta editada, comentame si resuelve tu problema.

Comment: Seguia teniendo el mismo fallo.

Comment: Finalmente utilicé esto: ` pip install --force-reinstall pywin32-223-py3-none-any.whl`

Comment: Gracias por aportar la solución, ¿puedo agregarla a la respuesta por si le sirve a alguien más que busque el mismo problema?